# how to create a user with firebase without signing in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        try {
            result.user.sendEmailVerification().then(function(){
            firebase.firestore().collection("Users").doc(result.user.uid).set({ name, email, imgUri });
            alert('Email Verification Have Been Send')
            firebase.auth().signOut();
          }).catch(function(error) {
            // An error happened.
          });
        } catch (e) {
          console.log("error1");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error));
```

I want to create the user then send a Verification email without singing in
how???

Comment: I saw it before writing this question but I thot there is a better way than using firebase-admin

Comment: If there was a better answer, it would've applied to that question too.

Comment: :/ thanks for the help